# How to use python scripts for analysing image of different graphs (in image format)

Tags: python, image, graph

I have several image file consisting of graphs with 5 different colors. I want to compare the colors and understand the similarities between them in the image files. How to use the python scripts to understand the similarities and differentiate the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" or is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor.

Comment: Get familiar with [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/PIL/) (python imaging library), or [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org), which is the fork of PIL. You can easily access and process images there.